# Re-use iOS MessageUI for custom in-app messaging

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Is it possible to reuse the view components from MessageUI to have an SMS-like messaging UI, but for custom app messaging instead of SMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, The MessageUI framework is locked down and no components are accessible for public use.

You would have to create your own interface unfortunately

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know.